# scroll bar with horizontal scroll sticking in the body

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience

I'm asking you for some help because I'm struggling a bit with CSS/JS, it's been a long time since I've practiced.
Basically I'm trying to make a section with a "sticky" title that scrolls horizontally with a block just below it that also stays sticky until I finish making this horizontal scrolling.
I managed to set up the structure but I think I need to add some more JS or modify what has been done. Currently I have 2 scrollbars I would like to have only one but that acts like I have two.

I put you the JSfiddle it will be more clear:

https://jsfiddle.net/ps4b10ro

```js
const spaceHolder = document.querySelector('.space-holder');
const horizontal = document.querySelector('.horizontal');
spaceHolder.style.height = `${calcDynamicHeight(horizontal)}px`;

function calcDynamicHeight(ref) {
  const vw = window.innerWidth;
  const vh = window.innerHeight;
  const objectWidth = ref.scrollWidth;
  return objectWidth - vw + vh + 150; // 150 is the padding (in pixels) desired on the right side of the .cards container. This can be set to whatever your styles dictate
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
  horizontal.style.transform = `translateX(-${sticky.offsetTop}px)`;
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  spaceHolder.style.height = `${calcDynamicHeight(horizontal)}px`;
});


var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {

  direction: 'vertical',
  mousewheelControl: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  // freeMode: true,
  // freeModeSticky: true
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.space-holder {
  background-color: #111;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  will-change: transform;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 0 0 0 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.horizontalText {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4em;
  padding: 0 3vw 0 3vw;
  width: 53vw;
  height: fit-content;
}

.etsy {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 22vh;
  height: 400px;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 350vh;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="module"></div>
<section class="container">
  <div class="space-holder">
    <div class="sticky">
      <div class="horizontal">
        <section role="feed" class="cards">
          <h2 class="horizontalText">Discovers our products</h2>
          <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="#EDD337"/>
                    </svg>
          <h2 class="horizontalText">Discovers our universe</h2>
          <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="#EDD337"/>
                    </svg>

          <h2 class="horizontalText">Discovers our products</h2>
          <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="#EDD337"/>
                    </svg>

          <h2 class="horizontalText">Discovers our universe</h2>
          <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="#EDD337"/>
                    </svg>
          <h2 class="horizontalText">Discovers our products</h2>
        </section>
      </div>
      <section class="etsy sticky">
        <section id="emporter container" class="blanc hori">
          <div class="wrap">
            <div class="defilement">
              <a href="/articles/damien-rice">
                <div class="cover" style="background:url(https://cdn.blogotheque.net/blogotheque/2019/11/18/fd9c7d252ab9de5569c9fcc96aabaaff.jpg) 50% 50%">
                  <div><img src="/packs/media/img/play-9e06fa89856b9d33899e081448a066f5.svg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <h3>Damien Rice</h3>
                <p>Soirée de Poche #54</p>
              </a>
              <a href="/articles/benjamin-booker-25870">
                <div class="cover" style="background:url(https://cdn.blogotheque.net/blogotheque/2020/01/02/27cd1d46f726bf3e4c15a79ad42e8e0a.png) 50% 50%">
                  <div><img src="/packs/media/img/play-9e06fa89856b9d33899e081448a066f5.svg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <h3>Benjamin Booker</h3>
                <p>Soirée de Poche #53</p>
              </a>
              <a href="/articles/shame">
                <div class="cover" style="background:url(https://cdn.blogotheque.net/blogotheque/2019/11/18/ec085ebc867db30fc41f8be3b247ec37.jpg) 50% 50%">
                  <div><img src="/packs/media/img/play-9e06fa89856b9d33899e081448a066f5.svg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <h3>Shame</h3>
                <p>Soirée de Poche #52</p>
              </a>
              <a href="/articles/hamilton-leithauser">
                <div class="cover" style="background:url(https://cdn.blogotheque.net/blogotheque/2019/12/05/b56f9fbe55b912ad931376338a655440.png) 50% 50%">
                  <div><img src="/packs/media/img/play-9e06fa89856b9d33899e081448a066f5.svg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <h3>Hamilton Leithauser</h3>
                <p>Soirée de Poche #51</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
              <!-- <img class="pointer gauche bloque" src="img/agaucheN.svg" alt="" /> -->
              <svg class="pointer gauche bloque" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#111" stroke-width="2" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 40)"><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="19"></circle><path d="m22.3823529 14-6.3823529 6.3823529 6.3823529 6.4852942"></path></g></svg>
              <!-- <img class="pointer droite" src="img/agaucheN.svg" alt="" /> -->
              <svg class="pointer droite" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#111" stroke-width="2" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 40)"><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="19"></circle><path d="m22.3823529 14-6.3823529 6.3823529 6.3823529 6.4852942"></path></g></svg>
              <div class="progress">
                <div style="transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </section>
      <div class="test">

      </div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help and or your advice

Comment: if you want a sticky element then you should also use `position: sticky;` and not JS which is totally unecessary for something that can be done with CSS by default.

Comment: Yeah I did it but the issue is not the sticky element but the scrolling bars who messed up my page, you can check the js fiddle it will be more clear

Comment: Anyone to help me ?? I am really struggling here